# defining class relationships in c# and visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, attributes, associations, diagram

Hey guys, in Visual Studio 2010 I can point to a bunch of classes and create a diagram.

However, the diagram by default doesn't recognize any relationships between the classes, except inheritance and implementations.

Is there a way, ideally by using Attributes, to define class and property relationships and associations in such a way that it is picked up by a new Class Diagram automatically?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can show the property on the class as a relationship by right-clicking it and choosing "Show as Association" or "Show as Collection Association".